# Prove $xy \gt (x-1)(y+1)$

Tags: inequality

I did a problem in competitive programming, the problem is to split a number into $x$ and $y$ ($x \leq y$) and make a new number by $(x - 1)(y + 1)$, do it until a new number different zero, and count how many different numbers can have by this split way.
It's easy for me but, when I draft, a new number is always lower than the original number. But I can't prove it. So, anyone can prove it to me?

$$x y > (x - 1) (y + 1)$$

Sorry for the story, but it's so boring if I just write an inequality. (maybe it's just an easy problem :D)

Comment: To improve your question you can also mention what you have tried and how much do you know about these types of problems. This will help people to understand about how much to explain to you and what tools to use. You should read https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for more info

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): **show your attempts.**

Comment: @AnneBauval I would encourage you to look at the standards regarding context, and to start helping people to think about things *other* than attempts.  In most cases, adding a perfunctory "attempt" to solve a problem actually makes the question *worse*, not better.  In this case, I think that the biggest problem is *clarity*.  I don't actually understand what the asker is trying to do, only that they *think* that the solution is to show that $xy > (x-1)(y+1)$.  Clarifying the *context* of the question would go a lot farther than simply adding "an attempt".

Comment: @Hải I genuinely do not understand what you are asking about.  Can you take a step back and clearly explain the problem that you are actually trying to solve?  I don't know what you mean by "splitting" a number into $x$ and $y$, nor what you are doing with this new number $(x-1)(y+1)$, nor what you mean by "do it until the number is different from zero" (isn't it *always* different from zero, unless $x=1$?).  This feels very much like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: I am aware of the standards. The context here is of no help. I think I do understand (like the three answerers) what the asker is wanting us to do for them. This was clear to us from the title, and from the central sentence "*a new number is always lower than the original number. But I can't prove it. So, anyone can prove it to me? $x y > (x - 1) (y + 1)$*". What is blatlantly lacking is some minimal effort to try to do it themself. This happens too often.

Comment: @AnneBauval Interestingly enough, I actually read the question quite differently.  As I read it, the user is trying to solve a programming problem, and they *believe* that they have reduced that programming problem to proving that $xy > (x-1)(y+1)$.  Reducing the problem to that state (to my eye) represents their "effort to try to do it themself".  But I think that this is an XY problem, as it is not even clear that this *is* the right approach.  Better to see the original problem as context, rather than a perfunctory effort.

Comment: Please also note that the point of "context" is not to force users to "make an effort" (this is a moralistic view of context---you are *bad* if you don't think for yourself).  Rather, the point of context is to create questions which, in a larger repository of questions, are more searchable, more likely to be discovered by future readers, and more likely to be helpful to those readers.  This idea that "effort" is the point strikes of Weberian "Protestant work ethic" moralism. :/

Comment: Effort is not "the" point, but (as many commenters recall to new users) is requested for this site not to become a "solution on demand" service. More importantly, the way askers show their attempts helps to understand better what they need and what they know.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that, since $x\leq y\Rightarrow x-y\leq 0$. So we have that
\begin{align}
(x-1)(y+1) &= xy-y+x-1 \\
& = xy + (x-y) - 1\\
& \leq xy-1 \\
& \lt xy
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

First, expand the right side of the equation.

$xy > (x-1)(y+1)$

$xy > (xy + x - y - 1)$

Subtract $xy$ from both sides:

$xy - xy > xy + x - y - 1 - xy$

$0 > x - y - 1$

Because $x$ is less than or equal to $y$, the expression $x - y$ will always be either $0$ or negative. When you subtract $1$ from either $0$ or a negative number, the result will be a negative number, which will always be less than $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$xy \overset{?}{>} (x - 1)(y + 1)$
$xy \overset{?}{>} xy + x - y - 1$

$x \leq y \implies y = x + k, k \geq 0, k \in R$

So ...
$xy \overset{?}{>} xy + x - (x + k) - 1$
$xy \overset{?}{>} xy - (k + 1)$